# Record loopback/monitoring with Audacity at full volume, independent of the speakers

Tags: linux, audio, recording, pulse-audio, audacity

I am using Audacity on Ubuntu with Pulseaudio.

Following [these instructions](https://support.audacityteam.org/basics/recording-desktop-audio) I can successfully record the output of my applications using Monitoring (i.e. not via microphone).

The problem is that the volume at which the output is recorded depends on the system output volume. I don't want to hear what I am recording. If I lower the volume to make it tolerable, the recording becomes too quiet.

How can I output low volume (ideally muted) to the speakers, but have Audacity record the signal at 100% volume?